# issue in student data updation

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a table of student details. and i have two csv files,these files contains updated information of existing students and new students data.if data not in student table which means the student left the school.

1. update new details for existing students
2. If student left school update status the to zero
3. If new student,then add as new row(with details from both csv)

Below is my code but in this second file information not getting updated.
i am attaching my code.if anybody have simple solution,please suggest

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "student";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM e_student";
    $result_main = $conn->query($sql);
    $filea = $_FILES['filea'];

    $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['filea']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ($ext == "csv" && $_FILES["filea"]["error"] == 0) {
        $target = "upload/" . $_FILES["filea"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filea"]["tmp_name"], $target);

        if (($handle = fopen($target, "r")) !== FALSE) {

            $array = $fields = array();
            $i = 0;

            while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
                if (empty($fields)) {
                    $fields = $row;
                    continue;
                }
                foreach ($row as $k => $value) {
                    $array[$i][$fields[$k]] = $value;
                }
                $i++;
            }

            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
    $ext1 = pathinfo($_FILES['fileb']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ($ext1 == "csv" && $_FILES["fileb"]["error"] == 0) {
        $target1 = "upload/" . $_FILES["fileb"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileb"]["tmp_name"], $target1);

        if (($handle = fopen($target1, "r")) !== FALSE) {

            $array1 = $fields1 = array();
            $j = 0;

            while (($row1 = fgetcsv($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
                if (empty($fields1)) {
                    $fields1 = $row1;
                    continue;
                }
                foreach ($row1 as $k => $value) {
                    $array1[$j][$fields1[$k]] = $value;
                }
                $j++;
            }

            fclose($handle);
        }
    }

    foreach ($result_main as $rel) {
        $clk = 'no';

        foreach ($array as $arr) {

if(isset($arr1['SCD']))
{
            if (strcmp(trim($rel['objId']), trim($arr['BCEID'])) == 0) {
                $clk = 'yes';
                $name = $arr['FirstName'];
                $conditn = $rel['objId'];

                $last_name = $arr['LegalSurname'];
                $year_level = $arr['YearLevelName'];
                $email = $arr['BCEEmail'];

                $username = $arr['BCELogin'];
                $StEnrollmentStatus = 1;
                $sql1 = "UPDATE e_student SET Name = '$name',Lastname='$last_name',stYearLevel='$year_level',email='$email',username='$username' WHERE objId ='$conditn'";

                $result = $conn->query($sql1);
                if($result)
                {
                updateparent($rel['objId'], $array1,$conn);
                }
            }
        }
        }
        if ($clk == 'no') {

            $conditn = $rel['objId'];
            $status = 0;
            $pastoral = "Not Currently Enrolled";
            $sql1 = "UPDATE e_student SET stEnrollmentStatus = '$status',stPastoral='$pastoral' WHERE objId ='$conditn'";

            $result = $conn->query($sql1);
        }
    }
    foreach ($array as $ar1) {


        foreach ($result_main as $rel1) {
            if (strcmp(trim($ar1['BCEID']), trim($rel1['objId'])) != 0) {

                $name = $ar1['FirstName'];

                $last_name = $ar1['LegalSurname'];
                $year_level = $ar1['YearLevelName'];
                $email = $ar1['BCEEmail'];
                $objid = $ar1['BCEID'];
                $username = $ar1['BCELogin'];
                $StEnrollmentStatus = 1;

                $sql3 = "INSERT INTO e_student(Name,Lastname,stYearLevel,email,objId,username,stEnrollmentStatus) VALUES('$name','$last_name','$year_level','$email','$objid','$username','$StEnrollmentStatus')";

                $result1 = $conn->query($sql3);
              if($result1)
              {
                updateparent1($objid, $array1,$conn);
              }
            }
        }
    }


    echo "<h3><center>SUCCESSFULLY UPDATED</center></h3>";
}

function updateparent($objid, $array1,$conn) {

    foreach ($array1 as $arr1) {
        if(isset($arr1['SCD']))
        {
        if (strcmp(trim($objid), trim($arr1['SCD'])) == 0) {
            $parent = $arr1['PTI1'] . $arr1['PFN1'] . $arr1['PSN1'];
            echo $parent;
            $email = $arr1['PEM1'];

        }
         $sql2 = "UPDATE e_student SET stParentName = '$parent',stParentEmail='$email' WHERE objId ='$objid'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql2);
        }
    }
}

function updateparent1($objid, $array1,$conn) {

    foreach ($array1 as $arr1) {


        if(isset($arr1['SCD']))
        {
              echo $arr1['SCD'];
        if (strcmp(trim($objid), trim($arr1['SCD'])) == 0) {

            $parent = $arr1['PTI1'] . $arr1['PFN1'] . $arr1['PSN1'];
            $email = $arr1['PEM1'];

        }
        $sql2 = "UPDATE e_student SET stParentName = '$parent',stParentEmail='$email' WHERE objId ='$objid'";
            $result = $conn->query($sql2);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add a description of you current issue and code that replicates it. Abstract versions don't work well. I'd propose parameterized queries but maybe you've already heard that??

Comment: dear friend ,issue with that two functions,update functions

Comment: Simplify the issue, there are +3 updates in your code..

Comment: can you help me. is there any simple code for this

Comment: Try to print update queries and check the query is correct or not

Comment: hello,i tried,issues in updation part

Comment: any simple solution for this, i felt my code is lengthy